# Dynamic ImageView 100% width in android Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am working with Xamarin and Visual studio. I want to add dynamically ImageView on my app from on an REST service.

My Main.axml is looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearOnlineOffers" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My MainActivity.cs is like this:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        string url = "http://192.168.90.102/test_api/handler.php/";

        Online[] onlines = CallRestService(url);
        LinearLayout layoutBase = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearOnlineOffers);

        foreach (Online online in onlines)
        {
            ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
            img.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
            img.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            layoutBase.AddView(img);
            Koush.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable(img, online.picture_filename);
        }
    }
```

I am trying to make the ImageView to be on the whole width of the screen. Unfortunatelly it looks like this:

[image]

What should I change for the images to be 100% of the screen ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to add the following line of code:

```
img.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
```

So in th end the code will be like this:

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

```
    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    string url = "http://192.168.90.102/test_api/handler.php/";

    Online[] onlines = CallRestService(url);
    LinearLayout layoutBase = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearOnlineOffers);

    foreach (Online online in onlines)
    {
        ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
        img.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
        img.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
        img.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        layoutBase.AddView(img);
        Koush.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable(img, online.picture_filename);
    }
}
```